# Uninitialized string offset: 36 Error ONLY when reloading page

Tags: php, web

I'm getting an error in my php page only when I reload it and sometimes it also comes without any warning..

I was trying to make a page where the user's can paste thier code and get the link to share it. The thing work's, but the error(s) on the main page are annoying.
Here's my full page code:

```
<?php
header("X-XSS-Protection: 1");
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
function getUserIP()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }
    return $ip;
}
$user_ip = getUserIP();
// for generating random filenames
$chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$namelength = 35;
$randomfilename = '';
for($i = 0; $i < $namelength; $i++)
{
    $randomfilename .= $chars[mt_rand(0, 36)];
}
if($_POST)
{
    $title = $_POST['postTitle'];
    $content = $_POST['postContent'];
    $filename = $randomfilename;
    $fname = $filename;
    $filename = 'pastes/' . $filename . '.html';
    $refresh = "Refresh:0; url=" . $filename;
    $date = date("Y.m.d");
    $time = date("h:i:sa");

    if(strlen($title) > 100)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Max 100 Characters Allowed!');</script>";
    }
    else if(strlen($title) <= 100)
    {
        $content = nl2br($content);
        $content = filter_var($content, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS, FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
        $title = filter_var($title, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS, FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
        $fname = filter_var($fname, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS, FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
        $link = 'http://openpaste.000webhostapp.com/' . $filename;
        $handle = fopen($filename, "a");
        fwrite($handle, "<html><head><title>" . $fname . "</title><link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'></head><body><h1>" . $title . "</h1>" . "DATE: " . $date . "<br>TIME: " . $time . "<h2>Your File Link: " . $link . "</h2><p>" . $content . "</p><br></body></html>");
        fclose($handle);

        $f = fopen("ip.txt", "a");
        fwrite($f, $user_ip . "\n");
        fclose($f);
        header($refresh);
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>OpenPaste | Home</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="overlay.css">
<style>
body{
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.nav{
    background-color: royalblue;
    padding: 2px;
    font-family: georgia, sans-serif, tahoma, arial;
}
.nav font,a{
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#icomenu{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
#icomenu:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1.0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
}
.overlay-content a{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.overlay-content a:hover{
    color: yellow;
}
.content{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: firebrick;
}
form{
    margin: 30px 0px 30px 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif, georgia, sans, tahoma, arial;
    font-size: 17px;
}
form input{
    width: 50%;
    text-align:center;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-family: sans-serif, georgia, sans, tahoma, arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #333;
}
form textarea{
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    height: 50%;
    font-family: sans-serif, georgia, sans, tahoma, arial;
    font-size: 17px;
}
form button{
    border: none;
    background-color: lime;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-family: sans-serif, georgia, sans, tahoma, arial;
    font-size: 17px;
}
form button:hover{
    background-color: royalblue;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a><br>
        <a href="https://github.com/NyanSniper101">Our Projects</a><br>
        <a href="about.php">About</a><br>
        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="nav">
<img id="icomenu" src="img/menu.png" onclick="openNav();">
<a href="index.php"><font color="white">OpenPaste</font></a>
</div>

<!-- BODY -->
<div class="main">

<div class="content">
<center>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="postTitle" placeholder="Your Title"><br>
<textarea rows="" cols="" name="postContent" placeholder="Your Paste.."></textarea><br>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Create Post</button>
</form>
</center>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried setting the error message to off, but still want to know why I get the error?
Here is the image of the error: [Error Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umavH.png).
You can find my project files here: [GitHub Project Repo](https://github.com/NyanSniper101/OpenPaste) incase you think that some asset is giving the problem.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: Thanks for replies :D

Comment: Change `if($_POST)` to `if(isset($_POST))`

Comment: The last index of `$chars` is 35, not 36.

Comment: Thanks :) Both the answers worked properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change:-

```
$randomfilename .= $chars[mt_rand(0, 36)];
```

to

```
$randomfilename .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
```

Because last index of `$chars` is 35 not 36 (as it started from 0 index).